# C# - Moving pictureboxes towards to another picturebox (NPC logic and Vectors)

Tags: c#, vector, game-physics, picturebox

I'm trying to move pictureboxes(NPCs) automatically towards to main character(pictureBox1), basically I want them to chase pB1. I'm very new to vectors. I couldn't understand the logic very well. First, let me show the codes.

```
  int pictx,picty,mcx,mcy;

    private void Monster_drag_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var pict in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
        {
                pictx = pict.Location.X;
                picty = pict.Location.Y;
                mcx = pictureBox1.Location.X;
                mcy = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
            if (pict.Name != "pictureBox1")
            {      
                ChaseVector(mcx, mcy, 0.5f);                    
            }
        }
    }
```

This was the timer event. Interval is 1000 by the way. Also I have a Struct that automatically creates pictureboxes. I'm pulling all pictureboxes that created with Struct by foreach as you can see.

And here is the Vector method;

```
public void ChaseVector(int x, int y, float speed)
    {
        float tx = x - pictx;
        float ty = y - picty;
        double length = Math.Sqrt(tx * tx + ty * ty);
        if (length < speed)
        {
            // move towards the goal
            pictx = (int)(pictx + speed * tx / length);
            picty = (int)(picty + speed * ty / length);
            foreach (var pict in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
            {
                if (pict.Name != "pictureBox1")
                {
                    pict.Location = new Point(pictx, picty);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // already there
            pictx = x;
            picty = y;
            foreach (var pict in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
            {
                if (pict.Name != "pictureBox1")
                {
                    pict.Location = new Point(pictx, picty);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I found this code on the stackoverflow. I really don't know anything about vectors. This code makes pictureboxes jump to main character. Flash them basically. I want them to chase mc slowly, like walking I mean. As if there is no speed, they are just jumping over the mc every time I move the character.

Waiting for your helps and if there is a better way to use Vectors please tell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is go read up on Vector movement, Google "Vector movement".  Just grabbing some code without understanding it is a disservice to yourself.  IMHO

Comment: Then use a loop to run the piturebox' location until it goes to the destination.

Comment: How? and what do you mean by running the piturebox' location?@TerribleDog